# Need a RegEx to match email To:

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match this email header row

```
To: everything here <myemail@domain.com>
```

I could have also this case which should be matched too

```
To: everything here <myemail@domain.com> <anotheremail@domain2.com>
```

In "everything here" there could be everything for example nothing,  words, spaces, double quotes and so on.

I am trying this Regular expression

```
/^To:(?:)<myemail\@domain\.com\>/gm
```

but it does not work. I understood that (?:) should match everything .

Comment: Use `^To: ([^<]+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly...

```
^To: (.*?) <.*$
```

Capture:

```
\1
```

Outputs:

```
everything here
```

https://regex101.com/r/GMi2rn/1

Comment: You should mention to grap Group 1.